# Java how to format a string?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have the following string:

```
String x = "020120765";
```

I want this string in the form of `02  0120765`. One possibility is:

```
x = x.substring(0,2) + " " + x.substring(2, x.length());
```

or:

```
x = String.format("%s %s", x.substring(0, 2), x.substring(2));
```

Is there any other better or elegant way? I'm thinking in the direction of regex. I have tried the following:

```
x = String.format("%s %s", x.split("\\d{2}"));
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can omit `x.length()` as the second argument to `substring`, and just write `x.substring(2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option

```
x = x.replaceAll("(..)(.+)", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: Good one. I changed to: `x.replaceFirst("(\\d{2})(\\d+)","$1 $2")`.
How could I not see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use a `StringBuilder` with its [`insert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert%28int,%20char%29) method:

```
x = new StringBuilder(x).insert(2, ' ').toString();
```

Comment: +1 it seems like the easiest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: +1. The position changes, so I only need to insert space if it matches the regex. Otherwise the default string should be the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in regex solution then you can try with

```
x = x.replaceAll("^..", "$0 ")
```

`^..` will match first first two characters. `$0` is reference to match from group `0` (which contains entire match) so `$0`will replace matched part with itself plus space.

Comment: This seems to me to be the most straightforward way to attack this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=String.format("%s %s",x.split("(?<=\\G.{2})", 2))
```

will not work because you are trying to pass an array in and you have too few arguments. You could, however, do it like this:

```
x=String.format("%s %s",x.split("(?<=\\G.{2})", 2)[0], x.split("(?<=\\G.{2})", 2)[1]);
```

Or, more neatly,

```
String[] arr = x.split("(?<=\\G.{2})", 2);
x = String.format("%s %s", arr[0], arr[1]);
```

EDIT: I am very inexperienced with regex so please excuse the previous incorrect regex patterns.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but `split("\\d{2}")` will remove part matched by `\\d{2}` which doesn't seem to be what OP wants.

Comment: I made the mistake of copying the OP's regex. Give me a few minutes and I will fix it

Comment: Please see the edit. The regex patterns are now correct and have been tested =)

Answer (score 0):

```
x.replaceAll("(?<=^..)", " ");
```